# Ссылки в php mail

Tags: email, php, html

пытаюсь отправить письмо через php mail, тег <a> не работает content-type: text/html, тег h1 работает и некоторые другие

Comment: пытаюсь оторвать ухо у соседа который живет за стенкой, методы и достижения не расскажу. Скажу только, что вроде рву именно ухо. Почему оно не отрывается!? Я сильно дергал. Задавайте вопросы грамотно и правильно и возможно вам ответят

Comment: Покажите скрипт, который отправляет письмо. Куда посылаете? Письмо открывают в браузере или почтовом клиенте? Какие теги работают?

Comment: @VenZell, работают теги h1,h2,h3 и т.д., input, form, center, left, right,div, class
Скрипт - просто функция с php mail, в заголовке только "Content-type:text/html", открывают в броузере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экранируй " бэкслешем

```
email='example@example.com';
$content= "Please click <a href=\"document.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> to read and download the terms and conditions.";

mail( $email, "Welcome", $content, "From: example@example.com");
```